# Defining a dictionary with generic value type in parent class method

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am very new to C# so this could be a stupid question.

I have a method in a parent class that returns a Dictionary. The problem is I need two different return types.

Here is the first one:

```
Dictionary<string, string>
```

Here is the second:

```
Dictionary<string, double>
```

Here is the method in the parent class:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Read(string directoryWithFilesToRead, ref Dictionary<string, string> returnDict)
{
        return read(directoryWithFilesToRead, ref returnDict);
}
```

Is it possible to create a generic type for the value argument and override it in the class implementing the method?

I think I could use `object` but I am trying to avoid casting (if I have to I will but I was wondering if there was a better way).

Comment: Seems like having a generic as the dictionary value should work. Side note: are you assigning the return value to `ref returnDict`? If so, you can make `Read` be `void`.

Comment: Good call, thanks musical_coder. Before I started refactoring I wasn't passing returnDict as ref but I think I can change that now. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Dictionary<string, T> Read<T>(string directoryWithFilesToRead, ref Dictionary<string, T> returnDict) {
        return read(directoryWithFilesToRead, ref returnDict);
}
```

Call it with `Read<SomeObject>("dir", new Dictionary<string, SomeObject>();`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) on generic methods.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. This is exactly what I was looking for! The link was very helpful as well.